# AvPlayer does not play video of photos app path

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to play video after selecting from my photos app. The path of my video looks like follows

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9235D829-F356-4C18-AE5B-BA7FE01AB67C/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.g0lCh1/output18442605A7-2B95-44BB-ADF9-7C52C0C6135D.mp4
```

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import PhotosUI
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func onClick(_ sender: Any) {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        config.selectionLimit = 1
        config.filter = .videos
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
        
        
        guard let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider else { return }
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
                    itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { [weak self] url, error in
                        
                        if let videoURL = url {
                            print(videoURL)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
                                let  playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
                                playerViewController.player = player
                                
                                
                                self?.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                                        playerViewController.player?.play()
                                    }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        
    }
}
```

What am i missing that its not playing in `AVPlayer`. I tried adding `Photos` permission in `info.plist` as well and in code

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("Photos access granted")
                // You can now access the user's photo library
            case .denied, .restricted:
                print("Photos access denied or restricted")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Photos access not determined")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown authorization status")
            }
        }
```

Comment: check this code https://github.com/ricsantos/PhotoLibraryPickerTest